# IMAP S22.IMAP copy messages between servers

Tags: c#, asp.net, imap

I'm maiking a tool to migrate acoounts between servers.

I'm using S22.IMAP dll, but when I call to Client.CopyMessages(mailIDs, Client2.DefaultMailbox), it

creates the messages in the initial account (duplicate the messages and no copy to the other account server)..

Can anyone help me? thanks
Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using S22.Imap;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace ImapPrueba1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static IEnumerable<MailMessage> messages;
        private static ImapClient imapClient = null;
        private static IEnumerable<string> mailboxes, mailboxes2;
        private static IEnumerable<uint> mailIDs;
        private static MailMessage mailMessage;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            using (ImapClient Client = new ImapClient("correo.correo.com", 993,
             "correo@correo.es", "xxxxxx", AuthMethod.Login, true))
            {
                ImapClient Client2 = new ImapClient("correonuevo.correonuevo.com", 993,
                    "correo@correo.es", "xxxxxx", AuthMethod.Login, true);
                mailboxes = Client.ListMailboxes();
                string mailbox, mailbox2;
                for (int i = 0; i <  mailboxes.Count(); i++) {
                    mailbox = mailboxes.ElementAt(i);
                    Client.DefaultMailbox = mailbox;
                    mailIDs = Client.Search(SearchCondition.All());
                    messages = Client.GetMessages(mailIDs);
                    //check the folder isn't in the destiny
                    mailboxes2 = Client2.ListMailboxes();
                    IEnumerable<string> items = mailboxes2.Where(p => p.Equals(mailbox));
                    int total = items.Count();
                    if (total == 0)
                    {
                        // set the folder in the destiny
                        Client2.CreateMailbox(mailbox);
                    }

                    Client2.DefaultMailbox = mailbox;
                    if (mailIDs.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        //copy to the destiny
                        Client.CopyMessages(mailIDs, Client2.DefaultMailbox);
                    }


                }

                label1.Text = "cambio";
            }

        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at e.g. the imapsync source code to see how it's done.

Comment: The copy command is for mailboxes on the same server, it is part of the protocol.  You would need to download the entire message and fetch it's internal date, then use APPEND on the other server to place it in the new account.  Or just use something like Thunderbird and drag and drop the messages between accounts.